# Draw CAShapeLayer strokeEnd circle one side

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, cashapelayer

> I have implemented a basic line drawing animation for a progress bar.The line has a round cap edge.When I moving the slider the line drawing the ending of line is having a rounded cap but in the starting its a square. below is the code I am using am i missing anything??

**Image Attached:** expected output

[image: expected output]

> Below Code I tried

```
@interface ViewController ()
{

CGPoint center;
CGFloat radius;

}

 @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
center = CGPointMake(200.0, 200.0);
self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];


 }
- (IBAction)greenSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
[self.view.layer addSublayer:[self drawArcAtCenter:center startAngle:sender.minimumValue endAngle:sender.value radius:100.0 withColor:[UIColor greenColor]]];
 }
 - (IBAction)blueSlider:(UISlider *)sender {
int value = (int)sender.value;
if (value > 360) {
    value = value % 90;
}
[self.view.layer addSublayer:[self drawArcAtCenter:center startAngle:sender.minimumValue endAngle:(float)value radius:100 withColor:[UIColor blueColor]]];
}


- (CAShapeLayer *) drawArcAtCenter:(CGPoint)newCenter startAngle:(CGFloat)sAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)bAngle radius:(CGFloat) radious withColor:(UIColor*) color
{
CGFloat begAngle = sAngle * 3.1459 / 180.0;
CGFloat endAngle = bAngle * 3.1459 / 180.0;


CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path addArcWithCenter:newCenter radius:radious startAngle:begAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];


layer.path = [path CGPath];
layer.strokeColor = [color CGColor];
layer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];;
layer.lineWidth = 50.0;
layer.strokeEnd = 50.0f;
layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
layer.cornerRadius = 30.0f;

return layer;
 }
```

[image: coming output]